# Simple Ruby Sinatra application runs, does not receive requests, times out

Tags: ruby, web-applications, timeout, sinatra, thin

Required Sinatra, got '/', did 'hello, world.', requested application root in browser and received nothing.

Literally the barest of bones Sinatra web application will not run as intended on my Mac, after previously working just fine. Page requests do not show up in the console.

I feel this may be due to force quitting an instance of a running application but after searching for a solution on the web I am at a loss and do not know how to rectify the issue.

edit:

```
require 'sinatra'
get '/' do
  'Hello, World.'
end
```

2. Problem does persist after a restart
3. Definitely the correct URL (exactly as I've been  working with all day). localhost:4567 as stated in the output when the application is run:

   == Sinatra (v1.4.7) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
   Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
   Maximum connections set to 1024
   Listening on localhost:4567, CTRL+C to stop

edit 2: scorched earth strategy; full reinstall with rvm fixed this issue.

Comment: a) Show code. b) Is there any output from your app? c) Are you sure you're running the right URL? d) Any firewalling being done? e) If you reboot, does the problem persist?

Comment: "I feel this may be due to force quitting an instance of a running application" can you elaborate on that?